# library for binary relations in haskell

Tags: haskell

I searched on google, searched on google with "site:haskell.org", and used hoogle. But I didn't find anything. There was some code that referenced "Data.Relation" in gf, the grammatical framework, but I couldn't find further information.

Is there a library for binary relations in haskell?

(I just want to do basic stuff like finding the transitive closure.)

ps: in agda, it is easy to find relations in the standard lib

=== EDIT: ===
I only need finite relations.
Just a function to get all related things (mathematical objects). And this also with transitive closure of the relation.

LATEST UPDATE:
I just found source code for Binary Relations on github:
https://github.com/fmaste/hgraph/blob/master/src/Data/Collection/Relation/Binary.hs

https://github.com/fmaste/hgraph/blob/master/src/Data/Collection/Relation/Binary/Simple.hs
 https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=Haskell&q=relation&repo=&start_value=1&type=Code&x=0&y=0

Comment: I'm not aware of anything.  What sort of observations do you need? eg. `type Rel a b = a -> b -> Bool` represents the decidable relations, but you cannot eg. enumerate its domain.  If you only need finite relations it is easy, but beyond that the design space is subtle.

Comment: Thanks luqui for your comment. So how should relations be implemented? With type Rel a b, with Data.Set or with Arrows?

Comment: UPDATE, I just found something on github: https://github.com/fmaste/hgraph/blob/9c7dae7578a1010e63cd6a55efb51ed97e3aa19d/src/Data/Collection/Relation/Binary/Simple.hs

Comment: that's what my question was about.  It depends on what you need from them.  You say you need to compute the transitive closure, but how do you want to observe the transitive closure?  A list of ordered pairs?  A boolean telling you when a pair is in it?  These things are equivalent mathematically but not computationally.  Why do you want a binary relations library -- this will help answer the question.

Comment: I'm working with SKOS (semantic web). There a skos concept can have multiple broader concepts, and I need some data structure to represent skos concepts. Also a skos concept can be related to multiple other skos concepts, and further features. Please see my other question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032731/haskell-data-structure-for-skos-semantic-web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/relacion/0.1/doc/html/Data-Relacion.html

Answer (score 0):

I think I just answer my question for now.

There are Binary Relations on github:
https://github.com/fmaste/hgraph/blob/master/src/Data/Collection/Relation/Binary/Simple.hs

It should work for what I need.
The library hgraph seems very interesting, but unfortunately it's not on hackage. So I missed it.

So the lesson learned is:
it's very important to search on the github (directly on the website). It also seems that github is not very well index by google, since searching for "binary relation haskell site:github.com" dosen't get the results I want (even searching for 'binary relation "Simple.hs" site:github.com' doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

The library that nponeccop links to is translated to English and is availably on Hackage:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relation

It's simple and gets the job done.